# Subset polygon data of SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by Distance to a Set of Coordinates in R?

Tags: r, polygon, distance, subset

I am learning and I made a very similar question when I hadn't learnt what a Spatial Polygons Data Frame was about 10 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193867/select-raster-in-ggplot-near-coastline.

Now, I have discovered the magic of SPDF and choropleth maps and have in essence the same question but with different types of files. I am still wrapping my head around S4 objects and I can't figure out how to subset certain mini-polygons `MUNICIPI` from my data set.

To the point!

**Context:**
I have a SPDF that contains these data:
[image: Dataframe inside cataconfidence]

**Aim:**

I would like to subset all `MUNICIPI` that are within a certain distance from the coast, clear data for the rest of the `MUNICIPI` and just work with the my new subset yet plotting the entire geometry.

A choropleth map of what I want [looks like this.](http://agricultura.gencat.cat/web/.content/ag_agricultura/ag02_sanitat_vegetal/ag02_02_plagues/documents/fitxers-binaris/mapa_zona_demarcada.pdf)

Let's say 20km as @urbandatascientist set in his answer to my first question and create a choropleth map of, for example, `upper_trees` with the subsetted `MUNICIPI`.

From the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193867/select-raster-in-ggplot-near-coastline post I also have the `list.of.polygon.boundaries` that we'll substract `MUNICIPI` coordinates from.

[**Data is here**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pAdCZ-lNLeaxpWhBUo3j6PQJa1L8w4VV?usp=sharing).

Once I subset the coastal `MUNICIPI`, I'm hoping the map will look [something like the green shaded region here.](http://agricultura.gencat.cat/web/.content/ag_agricultura/ag02_sanitat_vegetal/ag02_02_plagues/documents/fitxers-binaris/mapa_zona_demarcada.pdf)  I have also tried to make sure that coordinates are in the same between `list.of.polygon.boundaries`.

So far, here's my chloropleth map for the entire region using `upper_trees` as an example:

`tm_shape(catasense2)+
  tm_fill(col="upper_trees",n=8,style="quantile")+
    tm_layout(legend.outside =TRUE)`

[image: map for the whole region[2]]

Comment: Just to confirm: you tagged choropleth but the main question is "I would like to subset all MUNICIPI that are within a certain distance from the coast", so it's a **subset** problem, not display?

Comment: @Simbamangu Hi! That's a fair point. I tagged because in the end I want my dataset to look like this when plotted: http://agricultura.gencat.cat/web/.content/ag_agricultura/ag02_sanitat_vegetal/ag02_02_plagues/documents/fitxers-binaris/mapa_zona_demarcada.pdf but I guess it is more about subsetting. I will change the tag.

Comment: You may want to also look at this post with the understanding that spDists can calculate self distances or between feature distances. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132384/distance-to-nearest-point-for-every-point-same-spatialpointsdataframe-in-r/132392#132392

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I saw that link and all his data in is ONE SPDF. I have two things: the SPDF and the list (that contains two lists) of polygon boundaries. How can I compare these two things? (I'm sorry for the very basic question).

Comment: Thus my comment if x and y arguments are specified "spDists" can calculate distance between two different feature classes. Please see ?sp::spDists The resulting matrix object will represent the pairwise distances where rows and columns correspond to the features in each sp object.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Ok, I will this.

Comment: See my answer here as it more directly addresses your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273737/create-a-polygon-grid-from-spatialpoints-in-r/273787#273787